# How long are Tiles cached in Android Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

Using the standard UrlTileProvider https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/UrlTileProvider.html
to display PNG tiles on a map

- Are the tiles downloaded from the server cached ?
- If they are, how long ? Are the HTTP headers honored ?
- Is it possible to programmatically flush the cache ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried TileOverlay#clearTileCache() ?

Comment: Don't know if that method was there before but it is now. I've never had to actually implement that since the tiles update "often" enough, whatever that is.